# Use element text as CSS font-family

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/emerinA/1/edit

I'm trying to use the text of anchors located in a `.grab-typography` div and use that as the css font-family of that individual anchor.

JQuery/Javascript:

```
$('.grab-typography').find('a').css('font-family', $(this).text());
```

Here's the html.

```
<div class="grab-typography"><br>
  <a class="grab-serif" href="javascript:void(0)">serif</a>
  <a class="grab-sans" href="javascript:void(0)">sans</a>
  <a class="grab-arial" href="javascript:void(0)">arial</a>
  <a class="grab-arial-black" href="javascript:void(0)">arial black</a>
  <a class="grab-courier" href="javascript:void(0)">courier</a>
  <a class="grab-comic-sans-ms" href="javascript:void(0)">comic sans ms</a>
  <a class="grab-helvetica" href="javascript:void(0)">helvetica</a>
  <a class="grab-impact" href="javascript:void(0)">impact</a>
  <a class="grab-lucida-sans" href="javascript:void(0)">lucida sans</a>
  <a class="grab-tahoma" href="javascript:void(0)">tahoma</a>
  <a class="grab-times-new-roman" href="javascript:void(0)">times new roman
  </a>
  <a class="grab-verdana" href="javascript:void(0)">verdana</a>
</div>
```

The html if I add font-face html to it. (I'd like to avoid this as much as possible)

```
<div class="grab-typography"><br>
  <a class="grab-serif" href="javascript:void(0)" title="serif"><font face="serif">serif</font></a>
  <a class="grab-sans" href="javascript:void(0)" title="sans"><font face="sans">sans</font></a>
  <a class="grab-arial" href="javascript:void(0)" title="arial"><font face="arial">arial</font></a>
  <a class="grab-arial-black" href="javascript:void(0)" title="arial black"><font face="arial black">arial black</font></a>
  <a class="grab-courier" href="javascript:void(0)" title="courier"><font face="courier">courier</font></a>
  <a class="grab-comic-sans-ms" href="javascript:void(0)" title="comic sans ms"><font face="comic sans ms">comic sans ms</font></a>
  <a class="grab-helvetica" href="javascript:void(0)" title="helvetica"><font face="helvetica">helvetica</font></a>
  <a class="grab-impact" href="javascript:void(0)" title="impact"><font face="impact">impact</font></a>
  <a class="grab-lucida-sans" href="javascript:void(0)" title="lucida sans"><font face="lucida sans">lucida sans</font></a>
  <a class="grab-tahoma" href="javascript:void(0)" title="tahoma"><font face="tahoma">tahoma</font></a>
  <a class="grab-times-new-roman" href="javascript:void(0)" title="times new roman"><font face="times new roman">times new roman</font>
  </a>
  <a class="grab-verdana" href="javascript:void(0)" title="verdana"><font face="verdana">verdana</font></a>
</div>
```

I'm not having very much luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.grab-typography').find('a').css('font-family', function () {
    return $(this).text()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6KKq5/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about return.

Answer (score -1):

You could just grab the text in between tags?

```
$('.grab-typography').find('a[title="' + $(this).text() + '"]').text();
```

This way you don't need to worry about adding  tags

Test Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ktTh8/

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with using the text as the elements css font-family. Your demo is looking for a title which is not located in the html either.